# How to inspect React Native App UI Elements in Release build

Tags: android, ios, react-native, uielement, inspector

I'm trying to find out how to inspect UI elements in my react native application which I have downloaded from Appcenter. Is there anyway that I can connect my device to a browser or any tool which gives the option to inspect any app of iOS or android ?

Note: I know how to inspect the elements in debug mode.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You can use Flipper (https://fbflipper.com/docs/features/react-native/) or react native debugger (https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger)

Comment: @MichaelBahl I'm already using react-native-debugger, but it works only in debug mode. I have release build with me and I want to inspect element on the release build.

Comment: I think that wont be possible. AFAIK the app has to be in the debug mode.